# How to hide an Owned window shown after the Owner is minimized?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I know about the contract between [Owned windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owned_windows) and their Owner and that the Owned windows are hidden when the Owner is hidden. This is actually what I want. The problem is that if you show an Owned window *after* the Owner window is minimized then the Owned window is not hidden but is displayed normally on screen. In this case the WindowState of the Window is Minimized at start up so any Owned window that is shown is displayed on screen.

I know that I can call [ShowOwnedPopups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to force the OS to hide all the Owned windows but this only seems to work after the Owned window has actually been shown so you get a flicker on screen. I have tried explicitly hiding the window (e.g. removing the WS_VISIBLE bit or trying to alter the WM_SHOWCOMMAND such that it is shown hidden) but then the Owned window is not made visible when the Owner is restored. This is consistent with the documentation for the ShowOwnedPopups API whereby the only windows that are made visible are those hidden by the ShowOwnedPopups call.

So I'm looking for some way to either have the OS show the window in such a way that it is not made visible to the end user until the Owner is restored -or- a way to set a flag on the window so that the OS thinks it hid the window using ShowOwnedPopups and then I will manually hide the window and set that flag.

Note, the code that is showing the Owned windows isn't associated with the shell so it's not a simple matter of not showing the owned window until the owner is restored. This is part of a separate custom control and in this case it happens to be a WPF control so the control could even be used in an ElementHost so I can't just watch for the WindowState of the owning window either. Any windows API solution is welcomed though.

Comment: how is owned window shown after owner is minimized? clicking the owned window on the taskbar? if it's not a requirement you can hide the window on the taskbar. so, showing owned window becomes much harder to the user. please explain your case.

Comment: In this particular case the show is "automatic". The control is restoring its previous state which includes having some owned windows displayed. So just to be clear, the user put my control on their window. Their window has its WindowState set to Minimized. When the window is loaded it will be "shown as minimized" by the OS and when my control is initialized/loaded it is restoring its previous state and as part of that trying to show the owned windows that were shown the last time the control was used.

Comment: BTW if you want to see a simple example of what I mean, create a WPF application. Set the Window state of the main window it creates to Minimized. Hook the Loaded event. e.g. 'void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var w = new Window();
  w.Owner = this;
  w.Show();
}'

Answer (score 0):

As a little dirty trick (which i have used previously at one of my projects), I suggest creating the window outside of the visible area, minimize and move its position to visible area again when it is minimized. Check the code below.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var w = new Window();   // Create window
    w.Owner = this;         // Set this window as owner
    w.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.Manual; // Set startup location as manual
    w.Left = -10000;        // Set x position to -10000 (or anything which makes it out of bounds)
    w.Top = -10000;         // Set y position to -10000
    w.Show();               // Show window (it will not be shown, not even blink)
    w.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;   // Set window as minimized
    w.Left = 100;           // Set x position to 100 (or whatever you want)
    w.Top = 100;            // Set y position to 100 (or whatever you want)
}
```

Comment: Thanks but technically minimizing the Owner does not minimize the Owned windows. It just hides the window until the Owner is restored. I'm looking to do what the OS does and just have the Owned window hidden - again without having the flicker on screen. I may end up having to adjust the position so it's off screen and then call ShowOwnedPopups(hwnd, false) but I'd rather not if I can avoid it.

Comment: This is why I called it "dirty trick". This is obviously not the best way but a workaround.

Comment: Check this solution. It seems to be working. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f688e3b4-97e6-44e9-bd46-adff6c45f503

Comment: Thanks again but that too isn't the same. First, that would require knowing when the windowstate of the owner had changed to be able to call CoerceValue on the visibility. Also you'll find that when you minimize an owner and the owned windows are hidden the Visibility state is not changed. Just internally the OS is hiding the window and removing the WS_VISIBLE state. I'm really hoping to find a way to set the same internal state on the window that the OS does when it processes the SC_MINIMIZE (i.e. when it calls ShowOwnedPopups).